# How to aggregate with grouping in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have df like below

```
bin=[0,5,10]

sex age num
1    4   11     
1    3   12
2    2   13
2    10  14
```

I would like to sum in num and count age.
First I tried

```
df.groupby([df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)]).size()
```

or

```
df.groupby([df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)]).sum()
```

But I couldnt figure out how to aggregate and transform them. 
I want the following result.like

```
sex        age   num
 1 [0,5)    2     23   
 1 [5,10)   0      0
 2 [0,5)    1     13
 2 [5,10)   1     14
```

If I can get this result in simple way,please someone tell me how to transform original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and then add missing values by `unstack` + `stack`:

```
df = df.groupby([df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)])
       .agg({'num':'sum', 'age':'size'})
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .stack()
print (df)
             num  age
sex age              
1   (0, 5]    23    2
    (5, 10]    0    0
2   (0, 5]    13    1
    (5, 10]   14    1
```

Or create `MultiIndex` and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
bin=[0,5,10]
cats = pd.cut(df.age,bin)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.sex.unique(), cats.cat.categories])
df = df.groupby([df.sex,cats]).agg({'num':'sum', 'age':'size'}).reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
print (df)
           num  age
1 (0, 5]    23    2
  (5, 10]    0    0
2 (0, 5]    13    1
  (5, 10]   14    1
```